# Criptografia no Android

Tags: android

Eu quero guardar informações dentro de um banco de dados no Android.

Mas, por questão de segurança, gostaria de criptografar essas informações.

Alguém tem algum código simples pra isso? (e que seja possível reverter).

Comment: Que tipos de campos você quer ter criptografados? Apenas uma coluna específica? Um determinado conjunto de colunas? Você quer criptografar campos numéricos e chaves estrangeiras também? Quer criptografar todos os dados binários do banco de dados?

Comment: Você poderia guardar as informações codificadas com `AES`, e utilizar as chaves remotamente para decodificar essas informações no servidor e repassar ao usuário por exemplo. O usuário final não poderia decodificar porque só o servidor(_server-side_) poderia codificar e decodificar. Restando ao usuário apenas o resultado da operação.

Answer (score 0):

Eu tenho esse exemplo de criptografia que usei uma vez:

```
String senha= "";  
MessageDigest md = null;  
try {  
     md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");  
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {  
     e.printStackTrace();  
}  
BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest(pass.getBytes()));  
senha= hash.toString(16);
```

basicamente só converte string, mas pode adaptar, ja tem algo em que se basear.

Comment: Isso daí não é criptografia, você está apenas criando um hash. Por criptografia, entende-se algo reversível, de onde é possível recuperar-se o texto original a partir do texto criptografado. No hash, tal operação não é possível.